# Hide S3 bucket even from Admin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to hide an S3 AWS bucket from everyone, including Admin level users, except for one user (non-admin)? I've managed to create a bucket that only one user can access, but that still doesn't prevent Admins from using it and seeing the contents. This is for containing sensitive HR materials so it needs to be viewable only by the HR person assigned.

Comment: You should be asking on serverfault.com.  But as the current answer suggests, basically the answer is no.

Comment: What on earth is serverfault.com?

Comment: stackoverflow is a stackexchange site for asking programming questions. serverfault is a stackexchange site for asking server administration (including AWS) questions  https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't psychic enough to know that. And I saw another AWS question on here. I am a programmer, not a server administrator so this is all I knew about.

Comment: No apologies needed!  Sorry if I seemed to be implying you should already know that.  Was just trying to inform.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `Deny` policy to block other users (as per @jarmod) is good, but it won't stop the bucket from being visible nor will it prevent admins from being able to reverse the policy.

Another way to do it would be to **create a separate AWS account** and put the bucket in that other account. Then, add a Bucket Policy to that account granting access to the IAM User in the original account.

This would 'hide' the bucket from all users in the original account.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you were able to protect the bucket from users with admin-level credentials on AWS, those admin-level users would be able to modify the permissions on the bucket to gain access. Maybe consider encryption?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered an S3 bucket policy that denies access to everyone except the HR users and any HR automation processes that populate data into the S3 bucket, for example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy53216968",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny access except HR users and automation",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/hr-user",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/hr-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/hr-automation-role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Be careful with this kind of policy. You can easily lock everyone, including Admin users, out of the bucket if you make a mistake. In that case, you would need to resort to the root account to recover access to the bucket.

Note: this policy does not give any permissions to the HR users and automation processes. It simply denies all non-HR use. You still need to give permission to HR in the usual way (IAM policies).